# How to draw a rectangle on CameraBridgeViewBase in android opencv 3.1

Tags: java, android, opencv

I try this in `CameraFrame`

```
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();
Imgproc.rectangle(mRgba, new Point(10, 10), new Point(20, 20),new Scalar(0, 255, 0));
Imgproc.putText(mRgba, "====", new Point(10,10), 3, 1, new Scalar(255, 0, 0, 255), 2);
return mRgba;
```

The application compiles but it stops working on the device.
I think there is a problem with `new Point (,)`, but I am unsure if that really is the cause.

Comment: Your code is working fine for me. I hope you are using `org.opencv.core.Point`. Also make sure you are using this code in `onCameraFrame` callback method.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your codes, seems no problem. Open "Android Monitor" for debugging.